# Flutter Push notification (OneSignal) dosen't work in iOS devices

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I introduce OneSignal in my Flutter app, but it doesn't work in flutter!
I can't build my iPhone...

I want to make an push notification function.
I looked at the official document and done as it was.

Reference:

[flutter-sdk-setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup)

my code:

```
void main() async {
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  void _handleNotificationReceived(OSNotification notification) { 

  }

  OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler(_handleNotificationReceived);

  OneSignal.shared.init(
    "ID", 
    iOSSettings:
    {
    OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
    OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true
    }
  );

  OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);

  OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
  });

  OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  });

  OneSignal.shared.setPermissionObserver((OSPermissionStateChanges changes) {
  });

  OneSignal.shared.setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) {
  });

  OneSignal.shared.setEmailSubscriptionObserver((OSEmailSubscriptionStateChanges emailChanges) {
registered
  });
```

Android device success receiveing notification,
but...

Error code:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
   2019-08-02 20:09:54.715 xcodebuild[63419:2094699]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from deviceID was NULL
   2019-08-02 20:09:54.758 xcodebuild[63419:2094694]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from deviceID was NULL
   ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/../build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth'
   ld: warning: directory not found for option
   '-L/../build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_analytics'
   ld: warning: directory not found for option
   '-L/../build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_auth'
   ld: warning: directory not found for option
   '-L/../build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_core'
   ld: library not found for -lFirebaseAuth
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I suddenly started experiencing problems, I'm using a fork which works, maybe it will work for you (edit don't forget to use proper indentation in your pubspec) - `onesignalflutter: #^1.1.0
      git: 
        url: https://github.com/jmrobles/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK`

Comment: You shouldn't need to use jmrobles' fork anymore. This has been merged into the latest Flutter release